# How do I calculate $\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=(z-z_0)^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. How do I calculate for $\gamma :\left [ 0,2\pi \right ] \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma (t)=z_0+re^{it}$ with $r>0$ integral $\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz$?

My idea:
I'm not sure if  $\gamma(t)=z$ because if it is like that than $z-z_0=re^{it}$.
$\int_{\gamma }f(z)dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(re^{it})^ndt$.

But still this looks wierd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks weird because you forgot to substitute **also** the differentials:

$$z-z_0=re^{it}\implies \color{red}{dz=rie^{it}dt}\implies\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}(re^{it})^nrie^{it}dt=$$

$$=\begin{cases}&\left.\frac{(re^{it})^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_0^{2\pi}=\frac1{n+1}(r^{n+1}-r^{n+1})=0,\,&n\neq-1\\{}\\
&\int\limits_0^{2\pi}i\,dt=2\pi i,\,&n=-1\end{cases}$$

Comment: But isn't 1/0 not defined?

Comment: @Majica Yes, as far as I know it is undefined. Why?

Comment: How than it can be equal 2*pi*i when n=-1

Comment: @Majica Do the maths with the very same substitution as above. You get $$\int_0^{2\pi}i\,dt=2\pi i$$ as written...

Answer (score 1):

The line integral is *defined* by
$$ \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = \int_{a}^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \, dt. $$
Then you find
$$ \int_{\gamma} (z-z_0)^n \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} (re^{it})^n \cdot i e^{it} \, dt = ir^n \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n+1)t} \, dt, $$
which is zero unless $n=-1$.